# Why can Windows command prompt run this file?

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

I have a `./configure` file that I'm supposed to run by putting it in the command prompt. It works when I run it in the git prompt but when I run it in the Windows command prompt it gives me:

```
C:\cygwin\home\doxygen\configure> configure
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Even though I'm in the correct directory (and running `dir` shows me that the file is there) it still stays that it cannot find the file. This is the same for all files that don't have an extension on them. Why does this happen and how can I get this to work?

Comment: Try running it with absolute/full path

Comment: @g4ur4v I already have cygwin installed but I was using the Windows command prompt. Now I'm going to try the Cygwin command prompt.

Comment: @g4ur4v `C:\cygwin\home\doxygen\configure` doesn't work either.

Comment: use the cygwin command prompt, go to the correct directory and call `./configure`.

Comment: try this first on some linux based machine, it will not disturb you that much by windows related stuff.

Comment: Okay guys it "works" when I do it on the cygwin command prompt but I'm getting a few syntax errors. I'll figure it out guys so thanks!

Comment: In Windows, files are supposed to have extensions.  If they don't, some things won't work.  This is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

./configure is not a program. It's more of a shell script usually. My analogy may not be good but consider it to be the equivalent of windows batch files (in this case you can say it's a .sh without the extension). 
It will only run from a cygwin/unix shell.